# XNA interpolation on the CPU?

Tags: c#, xna, interpolation

**Interpolation on the CPU**

I would like to be able to do interpolation on the CPU.

Consider the following example:

`X1 | X2`

`-------`

`X3 | X4`

X1, X2, X3 and X4 are all pixels (in Vector4 format). They all have the following coordinates.

- X1: {X: 0, Y: 0}
- X2: {X: 1, Y: 0}
- X3: {X: 0, Y: 1}
- X4: {X: 1, Y: 1}

Now, I want to be able to do interpolation between the pixels given a Vector2.

So let's say I want the color of the coordinates {X: 0.348, Y: 0.129}.

How would I interpolate properly between the pixels?

**Why I want to do this**

I know this sounds crazy, but it's what I want to do. I am trying to simulate a GPU shader algorithm on the CPU. It's for a Perlin Noise generator. I've already got the 2D terrain generated through a pixel shader that way in the game, and I want to be able to (at a given X, Y and Z coordinate) check if there's a wall present there or not, using the exact same algorithm on the CPU.

If you want to know more about what I am trying to do, see this question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15667/perlin-noise-copying-the-algorithm-on-the-cpu

**Edit**

I posted this the wrong place. It should have been in "gamedev.stackexchange.com". I hope you have the answer anyway.

Comment: Not a crazy question at all... although providing information about what you are trying to achieve may provide additional information useful for answering the question.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Doing interpolation on the CPU is not so crazy. But if you're trying to get exactly the same results as the GPU - yeah, that's a little crazy. One thing you might need to consider is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219690(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is **bilinear interpolation** ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation)).

The XNA `Lerp` functions do linear interpolation - that is: one axis. Bi-linear is on two axes. Fortunately this is simply a matter of linearly interpolating on one axis (twice: once for each pair of inputs on that axis), and then linearly interpolating the two results.

So you'd do something like this:

```
Vector2 position = new Vector2(0.348f, 0.129f); // <- example data from question

Vector4 result = Vector4.Lerp(Vector4.Lerp(X1, X2, position.X),
                              Vector4.Lerp(X3, X4, position.X),
                              position.Y);
```